# user-selected variable interval options in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, variables, time, intervals

I'm currently having trouble using the `INTERVAL` function in Postgresql to specify a user-selectable variable.

I know how to use `INTERVAL` as in

> `date '2001-09-28' + INTERVAL '1 hour'`

but I want to allow the user to change the `1 hour` as needed.

Currently, I have found that

> `date '2001-09-28' + INTERVAL '{{number}} hour'`

works but I would love to be able to allow the timeframe (hour in this case) to be changeable by the user as well (to hour/day/week/month/etc). `date '2001-09-28' + interval '{{number}} {{timeframe}}'` doesn't work. I get the error

> `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 3, number of columns: 2.`

I have tried a variety of different methods, but none have yielded the answer I seek. I have tried searching for similar questions in the hopes of finding an answer, but I haven't found any.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide information on how the expression is being used? What are you using to fill in {{number}} and what does the resulting SQL statement look like?

Comment: @GeorgeS

I'm trying to allow the user to specify a time period and then adding that time period to a date, e.g. they can specify they want to know what day it is `2 weeks` in the future. They will fill in `2` into the `{{number}}` variable and `weeks` into the `{{timeframe}}` variable. 

The resulting output will be `2001-10-12`

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll need a `case` expression:

```
date '2001-09-28' + {{number}} * (case {{timeframe}}
                                      when 'hour' then interval '1 hour'
                                      when 'minute' then interval '1 minute'
                                      when 'second' then interval '1 second'
                                   end)
```

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful! A small syntax error though...I found that if i use `when 'hour' then INTERVAL '1 hour'` then it works instead of `when 'hour' then 'interval 1 hour'`

Comment: @davviid . . . Yes, `interval` should not be part of the string.